# Why does move sometimes leave empty folders behind?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have noticed that when moving a folder with non-trivial structure (it contains other folders, and not only files) sometimes Windows leaves behind empty copies of the directory structure. That is, the old location will contain a copy of all the folders, but not the files.

This happens sporadically so I cannot provide a way of reproducing. It happens when moving on the same drive as well as when moving between drives. A google search has shown that the problem has existed at least since Vista. I am on Windows 7 SP1.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Is there a way of solving it?